# Does Broly have 2 transformations?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-movies

Without counting Broly's supressed transformation (because it's an artificial transformation due to its necklace) does Broly have 2 transformations? I know this question is tricky because it could have different answers according to which version of Broly you are talking about (in Dragon Ball Heroes and other promotional animes there is a Broly SSJ3, Broly god, Broly SSJ4, etc), but how it is considering Broly from the movies in general. In the old non canon movies we've seen a greenish transformation in the first movie, and in the second movie we've seen a yellow transformation. Now for the new movie we've seen a greenish transformation and a yellow transformation from a promotional art. Does Broly have 2 transformations, a base form, a regular super saiyan transformation  (yellow) and a greenish legendary super saiyan transformation?

Old movie 1

[image]

Old movie 2

[image]

New movie

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe yes, one would be the regular super sayin and the other bersek mode Legendary super sayin mode. we kinda saw the same with kale as well

Answer (score 3):

It has been confirmed that the Broly in the new Dragon Ball Super movie is being introduced as a completely new character. Here is an [article](https://twitter.com/Herms98/status/1020175229241327617) with the brief summary of the story (As indicated in the trailer). Hence, if one were to look at the character designs for Broly:

[image: Broly Character Designs]

It was stated by Vegeta that he was growing stronger during the course of Battle. Hence the third picture is probably him powering up in his base form. The fourth picture is obviously him using his Super Saiyan form and finally, the last picture is the Legendary Super Saiyan Transformation (Unless the Name is changed), which we see at the end of the trailer.